# Create column of dictionaries with keys and values from other two columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a Pandas DataFrame where there are two columns that each contain lists and another column that contains the tuple pairs of the elements of those two lists. A toy example for the sake of convenience would be something like:

```
        col1       col2       col3       col4
0        'a'       [0, 1]     [8, 9]     [(0, 8), (1, 9)]
1        'b'       [2, 3]     [10, 11]   [(2, 10), (3, 11)]
2        'c'       [4, 5]     [12, 13]   [(4, 12), (5, 13)]
3        'd'       [6, 7]     [14, 15]   [(6, 14), (7, 15)]
```

What I want to do is to create a 5th column `col5` that contains dictionaries with the values from `col3` as keys and the values from `col2` as values. For example:

```
        col1       col2       col3       col4                 col5
0        'a'       [0, 1]     [8, 9]     [(0, 8), (1, 9)]     {'8': 0, '9': 1}
1        'b'       [2, 3]     [10, 11]   [(2, 10), (3, 11)]   {'10': 2, '11': 3}
2        'c'       [4, 5]     [12, 13]   [(4, 12), (5, 13)]   {'12': 4, '13': 5}
3        'd'       [6, 7]     [14, 15]   [(6, 14), (7, 15)]   {'14': 6, '15': 7}
```

I've tried methods such as

```
df['col5'] = dict(zip(df['col4'].apply(ast.literal_eval), df['col3'].apply(ast.literal_eval)))
```

but I receive an error. What would be the most appropriate way that I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If laready created `col4` is possible loop with `map`:

```
df['col5'] = df['col4'].map(lambda x: [{b:a} for a, b in ast.literal_eval(x)])
print (df)
  col1    col2      col3                col4                col5
0  'a'  [0, 1]    [8, 9]    [(0, 8), (1, 9)]    [{8: 0}, {9: 1}]
1  'b'  [2, 3]  [10, 11]  [(2, 10), (3, 11)]  [{10: 2}, {11: 3}]
2  'c'  [4, 5]  [12, 13]  [(4, 12), (5, 13)]  [{12: 4}, {13: 5}]
3  'd'  [6, 7]  [14, 15]  [(6, 14), (7, 15)]  [{14: 6}, {15: 7}]
```

Or if inputs are `col3` and `col2` use zip with `list comprehension`:

```
df['col5'] = [dict(zip(ast.literal_eval(a), ast.literal_eval(b))) 
              for a, b in zip(df['col3'], df['col2'])]

print (df)
  col1    col2      col3                col4            col5
0  'a'  [0, 1]    [8, 9]    [(0, 8), (1, 9)]    {8: 0, 9: 1}
1  'b'  [2, 3]  [10, 11]  [(2, 10), (3, 11)]  {10: 2, 11: 3}
2  'c'  [4, 5]  [12, 13]  [(4, 12), (5, 13)]  {12: 4, 13: 5}
3  'd'  [6, 7]  [14, 15]  [(6, 14), (7, 15)]  {14: 6, 15: 7}
```

Or solution with `apply`:

```
df['col5'] = (df.apply(lambda x:  dict(zip(ast.literal_eval(x['col3']), 
                                           ast.literal_eval(x['col2']))), axis=1))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. What do I do when some of the elements of the lists are "nan?" That's throwing a "malformed node or string" error whenever I try to perform these operations.

Comment: They're in `col2`.

Comment: @Seankala - then output should be empty dtct like `{}` or `NaN` in `col5` ?

Comment: That's what I also expected, but it's throwing an error for some reason... Perhaps this is a problem that is occurring because of a mistake I made when creating the original DataFrame. I'll try again from scratch.

Comment: Ah to answer your question, I was hoping that the `NaN` values would be `0` in `col5`. So the dictionary keys are mapped to `0`.

Comment: Yes, that works fine. I think that there's something wrong with the DataFrame itself. Your solution works fine with other toy DataFrames I've created.

Comment: It turns out the original DataFrame that I was using had NaN values that I hadn't accounted for. Should be fine after I take care of this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Seankala - simpliest it use `df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna('[0,0]')` before my solution, if nans are missing values

Comment: @Seankala - Or `df['col2'] = df['col2'].where(df['col2'].str.startswith('['),'[0,0]')`

Comment: Or use `df['col5'] = [dict(zip(ast.literal_eval(a), ast.literal_eval(b))) 
              if pd.notna(b)
              else dict(zip(ast.literal_eval(a), [0, 0])) 
              for a, b in zip(df['col3'], df['col2'])]`